# Can I save a picture from NetLogo into an Excel file?

Tags: excel, image, save, netlogo

I have a NetLogo model that has several variables which I have it automatically save into an Excel file.  I want to get the picture of the view, as well as the graph produced by the model, into the Excel file as well.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: do you mean the actual plot? You can create an image (as a png format file) with `export-interface` or `export-view` and then paste it into the Excel file later. But an Excel file is about numbers not images.

Comment: Thank you for your response @JenB! Yes, I want the plot to save each time I run it.  I can have it save the plot into a new png file every time using export- but I'm hoping I can save it in the Excel file so I can see the picture while looking at the numbers.  If that's not possible then I'd like to at least save multiple images (of the plots from each run) in the same file (even if not Excel) so I don't get a long list of files.

Comment: To throw a bad idea out there, you can use [the ExportThe extension](https://github.com/NetLogo/ExportThe-Extension) to get a copy of the view in base64 text format that you could then write to a text/csv file.   I have no idea if Excel can actually read base64-encoded graphics and show them as an image when a file is opened, but if it can then there might be a way to make this work.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to export multiple images into a single file, Excel or otherwise. But you can certainly use `export-plot` to export the values that are used to create the plot, and then just have Excel create a plot from those values.